# How to exit from shell launcher in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, kiosk

On a Windows 10 enterprise machine I have configured shell launcher according to this [technical article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher#configurare-una-shell-personalizzata-con-powershellconfigure-a-custom-shell-using-powershell).

I only configured a custom shell for **user1**, who is not an admin; I didn't set a default shell nor changed the shell for administrators. When I log in with **user1** credentials everything works as expected.

Otherwise when I log in as an administrator I only have a command window. I can launch explorer from it but I have other limitations.

This is an unexpected behavior, I thought other users would not been affected from the custom shell set for **user1**. How can I gain full control of the machine when I need to do administrative tasks ? Am I supposed to disable shell launcher via powershell ?

Comment: The referenced article is for setting up a shell on a **kiosk** system, not one for general use. The article referenced specifically calls out the fact that it _replaces explorer.exe_. However, it appears that [this article, _also_ about Shell Launcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher), provides information on using Shell Launcher for customizing the shell on a per-user basis.

Comment: It seems I solved the problem. I set the default shell to **explorer.exe**, so nothing change for every other user except **user1**. According to my experience setting a custom shell for a single user SID causes the default shell to be set to **cmd**.